# Qt Creator cannot preview QString when debugging

Tags: qt

- List item
- Qt-Creator 2.2.0
- OSX Lion
- "Use debugger helpers" is checked
- "Built" and "re-built" all the helpers.

Still... break point on method with QString and the content of the QString cannot be previewed on the debugging pane unless I go to the memory window and search for it manually with the address. I have to use qDebug to dump strings out as if we're in 1983. This use to work and I have no idea what happened to it. Every other type works well.

On Windows 7, the debugger *can* preview QString objects.

Comment: Are the versions of the one on mac and one on windows the same?

Comment: okay, going on a hunger strike until I can evaluate QStrings on Qt under OSX :-)

Comment: Try your luck on superuser, the question fits there more.

Comment: Could you share how you solved it? the link in the accepted answer is dead...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same problem but after some research I found the answer here:
http://silvermace.com/2010/09/qt-creator-debugger-not-displaying-qstring/
I had to chose the correct qmake path and then I had to build the GDB Helper.

As the original site is gone, here are the steps:

1. sudo rm /usr/local/Qt4.6/qtc-debugging-helper/libgdbmacros.dylib
2. Start Qt Creator
3. Qt Creator -> Preferences -> Select the “Qt” tab -> Select “Qt in PATH” under “Auto-detect”
4. There should be a red cross next to the label “Debugging Helper.” On the right of that there’s a rebuild button – hit it and wait.
5. The red cross should turn into a green tick.
6. Clean & Build your project.

Comment: Thanks. unfortunately it didn't work for me. Same results... debugger unable to evaluate QStrings...

Comment: The link is dead: wouldn't it be better to post the solution directly?

Answer (score 0):

Pastebin the debugger log (right pane of Windows->views->Debugger Log) somewhere and post the link here. And perhaps the log file of the debugger helper rebuilding that you tried?